# How to print a set number of strings to output? C++

Tags: c++, printing, cmd, linked-list, iostream

I am having a difficult time printing the data from 2 separate linked list. I have the right width, and indention. I just can't figure out how to get the data to only print 8 strings per line.

### My Print Function

```
void print(string print_data, int node_no) {
    Node* p = head;
    Node* temp;
    int i;
    int number = node_no;

    if(node_no == 0 || node_no == 1) {
        temp = p;
    }
    else {
        i = 1;
        while(i < node_no) {
            i = i +1;
            temp = p->next;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    cout << left;
    for(int i = 0; i < temp->data; ++i) {
        cout << setw(4) << print_data << " ";
    }
}
```

Also I can't set this by using the modulo b/c I am printing a single node from each list at one time, so my i in the for loop can not be used to figure out when to end a line.

Comment: Variable `temp` is unnecessary and `left` is undefined.

Comment: This code appears to output the string `print_data` repeatedly, the number of times specified by the `data` member of the `node_no`th node. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't know how many strings are already printed on the given line when executing the loop at the bottom of your `print()` function. If that is the problem, you'd need to store the information on how many string are already on the line somewhere. One location to store this data could be in the stream's `iword()`:

```
// at an appropriate location, probably at namespace scope outside the function:
static int const iword_index = std::ios_base::xalloc();

// ...
for(int i = 0; i < temp->data; ++i) {
    out << setw(4) << print_data << " ";
    if (++out.iword(iword_index) == 8) {
        out << '\n';
        out.iword(iword_index) = 0;
    }
}
```

In principle it would also be possible to create a suitable filtering stream buffer which keeps tracks of the number of words per line. Although this is a more general solution it is also somewhat more complicated.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly my problem. But I'm slightly confused on the stream's iword()?

Comment: `iword()` is simply providing access to a reference of an `int` which is associated with the index passed as argument (I had accidentally omitted it in the second use). Initially, the `int` will have the value `0` and in the code above it is simply used to count the number of times a word is printed.

Comment: Ended up just using the idea of keeping track of the word count using a function, and the count would reset every time I hit 8 words or after every full print.